# Keep highlighting the cell when user deselect

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, highlight

I'm using Xamarin Forms `ListView` as a SideBar. How can I prevent users from deselecting cell? Or at least keep highlighting the cell when users deselect it.
This is how I'm binding

---

```
                   <ListView x:Name="listView" SelectionMode="Single">
                        <ListView.ItemsSource>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                <x:String>Management</x:String>
                                <x:String>Information</x:String>
                                <x:String>Language</x:String>
                                <x:String>Settings</x:String>
                            </x:Array>
                        </ListView.ItemsSource>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextCell Text="{Binding}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: You can also use a CollectionView with multiselect :) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, when you select item from ListView, this item highlighting, you want to this item still highlighting when this item is not selected state. It seems that you want to select multiple item from ListView.

I've made a sample, you can take a look:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView
            ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            SelectionMode="Single">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding background}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
                                TextColor="Fuchsia" />
                            <BoxView
                                HorizontalOptions="End"
                                IsVisible="{Binding Selected}"
                                Color="Fuchsia" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

public partial class Page10 : ContentPage
{
    public Page10 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.BindingContext = new MultiSelectItemsViewModel();
    }

    private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Model m = e.Item as Model;

        if(m!=null)
        {
            m.Selected = !m.Selected;
            if(m.background==Color.White)
            {
                m.background = Color.BlueViolet;
            }
            else
            {
                m.background = Color.White;
            }
        }

    }
}

public class Model:ViewModelBase
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    private bool _Selected;
   
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _Selected; }
        set
        {
            _Selected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }
    private Color _background;
    public Color background
    {
        get { return _background; }
        set
        {
            _background = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("background");
        }
    }
}

public class MultiSelectItemsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Items { get; set; }
    

    public MultiSelectItemsViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "AAA", Selected = false,background=Color.White });
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "BBB", Selected = false , background = Color.White });
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "CCC", Selected = false, background = Color.White });
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "DDD", Selected = false, background = Color.White });
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "EEE", Selected = false, background = Color.White });
      
    }

   
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Don't allow user to unselect the selected item.

```
 private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Model m = e.Item as Model;

        if(m!=null)
        {
            m.Selected = true;
            m.background = Color.Blue;

            
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are taking it wrong. What I want is there is always 1 highlighted Item and just 1. User cant do anything to unhighlight it

Comment: @JonFlame, you mean that you can not disselect the selected item once you selected it?

Comment: That's what I want. I want user **can not unselect** the selected Item once they selected it

Comment: @JonFlame, If you don't allow user to unselect item once they select it, you can see my update, just change some code in ListView_ItemTapped event.

Comment: It's worked, thank you. But can we do this without binding anything?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, I've done something similar but with controls inside each row, like a checkbox.
https://xamarinhelp.com/multiselect-listview-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I just want to use something available in `ListView`. I don't want to Bind anything into it

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectedItem` property of the ListView. As long as `SelectedItem` property is not set back to null, the currently selected item will remain highlighted.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work. It kept the `SelectedItem` but not the highlight